# TypeScript: Using jquery $(this) in event

Tags: jquery, typescript

HTML:

```
<div>
<button data-id="3">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

In classic jQuery I would do:

```
$("div").on("click","button", test);

function test(){
   alert($(this).data("id"));
}
```

To get the `data-id` of the clicked element

In TypeScript (in a class) I use:

```
class foo { ...
 $("div").on("click", "button", (event) => this.test());

 public test(){
    alert($(this).data("id")); // "undefined"
    console.log($(this));
 }

....
}
```

Here I don't get the clicked element - `$(this)` is the instance of the class.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You don't do anything wrong - it's TypeScript been a bit too helpful. Inside class methods `this` is treated as though it always refer to the corresponding object. So you have two solutions - either catch the clicked element with `event.target` property, or define the handler function outside of that class.

Comment: As I can see most of the answers are incomplete or wrong. please visit my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159416/using-the-this-in-event-handler-with-typescript/38159643?noredirect=1#comment63747929_38159643

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to [Typescript's spec](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) "this" is referring to the instance of class the method belongs to/is called on.

You could use the target attribute of the event object passed to the callback:

```
class foo {
  public test(evt){
    alert($(evt.target).data("id")); // "undefined"
    console.log($(evt.target));
  }
}
```

Or `event.currentTarget` depending on if you want to get the element actually clicked on or the element which captured the event.

Comment: i use **$("div").on("click", "button", (event) => this.test(event));** and in the function:
**public test(element:JQueryEventObject){ $(element.target)  }**.... it works - thank you!

Comment: @user3351722 : thanks. This solves the actual problem of accessing both the event target and the class.

Answer (score 23):

Using `event.currentTarget` worked for me when trying to get a data attribute of what was clicked.

```
$('.elementID').click(e => this.clickedElement(e));


clickedElement(e: JQueryEventObject) {
    var iWasClickedData = $(this).data('key'); // will not work
    var iwasClickedDataFixed = $(e.currentTarget).data('key'); // will work
}
```

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

By using arrow functions `(event) => TypeScript` is giving you a lexically bound this. (In compiled code a previously captured instance called `_this`)

If you switch to using vanilla function syntax you should be able to use `$(this)` as you would normally:

```
$("div").on("click", "button", function(event) { this.test()});
```

Obviously you have an issue with the instance of the test method being called but I thought it worth sharing.

Comment: I had to use this answer rather than the suggested ones because I had the same issue trying to extend jQuery.fn with my own extension method, which doesn't provide an alternative reference to 'this' like events do.