# using the $(this) in event handler with typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I saw many answers in the stackoverflow that were answered wrong and I wanted to make it clear at least for myself.
the old question: using the $(this) in event handler with typescript. most of the answer was about using `event.target`

The first problem is it's not only the `event.target` (most of the answer in stack overflow). I need to check for IE specific terms too (anyone that remember days before jquery at least knows that).

the second problem is propagation.
let say I have some elements like this

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-open"><span>something is here</span></i></a>
```

and i created a click event on `a` like this:

```
$("a").click((evt)=>{
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    console.log($(target));
});
```

if there is enough padding and margin around this elements with proper clicking i can get the target as either of three elements `a`, `i`, `span`

now the headache will start, then I need to check what it clicked, is it the `a` or the `span` or even the `i`

time to time it bring redundant codes that was not needed if i could access to $(this).
the beauty of $(this) is that it is returning the item that I was listening to, cross browser!

in my case $(this) always reference to `a` and not any of the other child element. so i know for example if I want to access the `i` i need to search in child elements. but in the way that Typescript make me to use event i need to check where in the DOM i am (target is `span` or `a` or `i` !!!), then I decide to climb or get down in the tree or do the changes in the current element.

I know there should be a better way. so the question is what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the answer was lying on instance methods,

from typescript 0.91 there is a different between normal methods and instance methods and its `this`. this difference let me to access to both this in class instance and this in jquery.

a sample class would be like this:

```
class sample{

    field1:number;

    constructor(){
        field1=1;
    }

    method1(){

        let self=this;
        $("a").click(function(event){       
            var target=$(this);  
            console.log(target); // here i have access to the jquery one
            console.log(self.field1); // here i have access to the class level
        });
    }

    method2(){

        $("a").click((event)=>{     
            var target=$(this);  // this will not work bcs it's an instance method 
                                 // the this is refering to the class

            console.log(target); 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `event.currentTarget` instead of target:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

ps: Do you really support IE8 ? Google, Microsoft and all don't even support it anymore on most of their websites.

Comment: as the link you attached, IE 6 to 8 doesn't support event.currentTarget. any other solution?
yes, I need to support it, most of the banks and government offices still are using IE8, next time you passed HSBC bank, go to the counter and ask the IE version

Comment: ok, what error do you get then when you call $(this) in typescript in a jquery event handler? it should work exactly the same as in javascript at runtime; but you might get a type error which we may look into.

Comment: i was using instance method. i changed it to normal function and now it works fine, i carry the class reference from the upper scope. please see my answer